# Parsing Console Output to Individual Strings

Tags: python, console, output

I am writing an automated pen-testing tool that grabs the IPs of all active hosts connected to the network. It outputs a list into the console, and I want to take these and create an [inquirer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inquirer) question where the user may select one using the arrow keys.

```
import nmap
import subprocess
rhostcommand = "nmap -n -sn " + lhost.rstrip()[:-3] + "-255 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'"
pst = subprocess.Popen(rhostcommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = pst.stdout.read()
if output == None:
    print "Couldn't resolve Remote Host IPs.\n[ref. 0000003]"
else:
    print "Remote Host IPs:\n"
    print output.rstrip()
```

This is my code to create the IP list. Here is a sample output:

```
Remote Host IPs:

172.16.96.1
172.16.96.2
172.16.96.113
172.16.96.116
172.16.96.117
172.16.96.212
172.16.96.218
172.16.96.219
172.16.96.225
```

This is my current code for the inquiry, I will explain the errors:

```
import inquirer
questions = [
        inquirer.List('rhostips',
            message="Choose target IP"
            choices=int(output),
        ),
]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
print answers ['rhostips']
```

**The problems I am having are with the `choices=int(output)` line.** I need to make the `output` formatted so [inquirer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inquirer) can recognize it. The accepted format is as follows:

```
import inquirer
questions = [
  inquirer.List('size',
                message="What size do you need?",
                choices=['Jumbo', 'Large', 'Standard', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Micro'],
            ),
]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
```

Thank you for any answers you may have.

**Solved, Correct Code Below:**

```
outputsplit = output.splitlines()

import inquirer
questions = [
        inquirer.List('rhostips',
            message="Choose target IP",
            choices=outputsplit,
        ),
]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
print answers ['rhostips']
```

Used the `splitlines` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not my strongest language, but you should be able to split the lines in `output` by using `output.splitlines()` (which will return an array of strings). From there you can pass it into the inquirer `choices` parameter.